# The logs of my Mongo database grow by 100G per month

Tags: mongodb, performance, logging

I have inherited the administration of a Mongo DB with basically zero knowledge on how it was set up and how to manage it.

I notice that its logs are growing at an absurd rate of 100G per month (or 2M per minute, constantly). This is despite the verbosity of the DB set to its default level (aka lowest level according to the docs).

I am not sure how to even diagnose what's going on, again because a complete lack of knowledge. Do you have any recommendation?

---

*More details on the system:*

This database is used for distributed data production. Several "clients" query periodically the DB for tasks to be done. Tasks are then executed, and the clients then send basic information about them back to the DB.

There are 4 sites, the reading happens every 5-10 minutes. There is between 100 and 1000 tasks per site, and they give live signs every 5-15 minutes.

Comment: You can try _log rotation_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation

Comment: The problem with log rotation is that it treats the symptom but not the cause

Answer (score 0):

First download [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Then you may run a quick analyze of the log file.

Here is an example:

```
$ jq -c '{s:.s, c:.c}' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log | sort | uniq -c
    848 {"s":"I","c":"-"}
   5395 {"s":"I","c":"ACCESS"}
  35998 {"s":"I","c":"COMMAND"}
   3729 {"s":"I","c":"CONNPOOL"}
      5 {"s":"I","c":"CONTROL"}
   2259 {"s":"I","c":"INDEX"}
   4612 {"s":"I","c":"MIGRATE"}
  21723 {"s":"I","c":"NETWORK"}
  18987 {"s":"I","c":"SHARDING"}
   7236 {"s":"I","c":"SH_REFR"}
   5786 {"s":"I","c":"STORAGE"}
    219 {"s":"I","c":"WRITE"}
   7224 {"s":"W","c":"NETWORK"}
    411 {"s":"W","c":"SHARDING"}
```

Most logs are `{"s":"I","c":"COMMAND"}`, so have a look at them

```
$ jq -c 'select(.s == "I") | select(.c == "COMMAND") | {msg: .msg}' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log | sort | uniq -c
     94 {"msg":"Attempting to kill cursor"}
     98 {"msg":"Attempting to kill operation"}
   3547 {"msg":"CMD: drop"}
     94 {"msg":"Killed cursor"}
    843 {"msg":"renameCollectionForCommand"}
  31681 {"msg":"Slow query"}
```

Majority is message is "Slow query", so by using Google you get
[db.setProfilingLevel()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#std-label-set-profiling-level-options-slowms). By setting higher value for `operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs` the number of logs should get less.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know of this utility. I have downloaded it and ran `$ ./jq -c '{s:.s, c:.c}' /local/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log | sort | uniq -c`, but then I get `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 14` . Is there a problem somewhere?

Comment: Which version of MonogDB do you use? Older versions use CSV format instead of JSON format. In this case skip `jq` and try simple `grep`